# LeafLet implementation on Next JS 13

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, leaflet, react-leaflet

I trying to implement a LeafLet map component in my Next JS 13.0.1 project, but I'm having a problem with the render of the map component.

In the first load of the map component, this error appears:

```
ReferenceError: window is not defined
    at eval (webpack-internal:///(sc_client)/./node_modules/leaflet/dist/leaflet-src.js:229:19)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///(sc_client)/./node_modules/leaflet/dist/leaflet-src.js:7:11)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///(sc_client)/./node_modules/leaflet/dist/leaflet-src.js:9:3)
    at Object.(sc_client)/./node_modules/leaflet/dist/leaflet-src.js (C:\desenvolvimento\estacionai-front\.next\server\app\page.js:482:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (C:\desenvolvimento\estacionai-front\.next\server\webpack-runtime.js:33:43)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///(sc_client)/./node_modules/leaflet-defaulticon-compatibility/dist/leaflet-defaulticon-compatibility.js:2:18)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///(sc_client)/./node_modules/leaflet-defaulticon-compatibility/dist/leaflet-defaulticon-compatibility.js:4:2)
    at Object.(sc_client)/./node_modules/leaflet-defaulticon-compatibility/dist/leaflet-defaulticon-compatibility.js (C:\desenvolvimento\estacionai-front\.next\server\app\page.js:472:1)  
    at __webpack_require__ (C:\desenvolvimento\estacionai-front\.next\server\webpack-runtime.js:33:43)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///(sc_client)/./components/Mapa.tsx:11:91)
```

anyways, the map loads, but things like markes do not appear

[image]

the real problem is when the page is reloaded, being a hard reload or a Link reference.
this error appears:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'default')
    at resolveModuleMetaData (webpack-internal:///(sc_server)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-server-dom-webpack/server.browser.js:195:82)
    at serializeModuleReference (webpack-internal:///(sc_server)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-server-dom-webpack/server.browser.js:1298:50)
    at resolveModelToJSON (webpack-internal:///(sc_server)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-server-dom-webpack/server.browser.js:1660:40)
    at Array.toJSON (webpack-internal:///(sc_server)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-server-dom-webpack/server.browser.js:1081:40)
    at stringify (<anonymous>)
    at processModelChunk (webpack-internal:///(sc_server)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-server-dom-webpack/server.browser.js:163:36)
    at retryTask (webpack-internal:///(sc_server)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-server-dom-webpack/server.browser.js:1823:50)
    at performWork (webpack-internal:///(sc_server)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-server-dom-webpack/server.browser.js:1856:33)
    at AsyncLocalStorage.run (node:async_hooks:330:14)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///(sc_server)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-server-dom-webpack/server.browser.js:1934:55) {
  digest: '699076802'
}
```

After this error, the page do not load

[image: blank page]
[image]

- Project Structure:

[image: project structure]

- Mapa.tsx(map component)

```js
'use-client';

import { useState } from 'react';
import 'leaflet/dist/leaflet.css';
import 'leaflet-defaulticon-compatibility/dist/leaflet-defaulticon-compatibility.css'
import "leaflet-defaulticon-compatibility";
import { MapContainer, TileLayer, Marker, useMap } from 'react-leaflet';


export default function Map() {
  const [geoData, setGeoData] = useState({ lat: 64.536634, lng: 16.779852 });

  return (
    <MapContainer center={[geoData.lat, geoData.lng]} zoom={12} style={{ height: '90vh' }}>
      <TileLayer
         attribution='&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
         url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
       />
      {geoData.lat && geoData.lng && (
        <Marker position={[geoData.lat, geoData.lng]} />
      )}
    </MapContainer>
  );
}
```

- Home component (app/page.tsx)

```js
'use client';

import Link from "next/link";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Mapa from "../components/Mapa";

export default function Home(){
  
  return (
    <div>
      <Link href='/pontos'>Pontos</Link>
      <Mapa />
    </div>
  )
}
```

- package.json

```js
{
  "name": "estacionai-front",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/node": "18.11.9",
    "@types/react": "18.0.24",
    "@types/react-dom": "18.0.8",
    "leaflet": "^1.9.2",
    "leaflet-defaulticon-compatibility": "^0.1.1",
    "leaflet-geosearch": "^3.7.0",
    "next": "^13.0.1",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-leaflet": "^4.1.0",
    "typescript": "4.8.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/leaflet": "^1.9.0",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.13",
    "postcss": "^8.4.18",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.2.1"
  }
}
```

I tried to use the dynamic() and import() function from Next but without successm, i think the only way to load the component is using the 'use client' directive in both the map component and page component

Comment: Just upgraded to next 13, without any issues. However I dynamically load my leaflet components. https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/dynamic-import
Let me know if you want me to share more code

Comment: you are using the new app/directory routing or the pre-existing pages routing to load leaflet components?

Comment: I use pages, since I could not bother to use app since its still experimental. Will probably go over in the future when its stable. So please update this thread if you find a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have the exact same issue and I was able to get it working doing something like this:

```
// this is your current Map file
export default function ClientMap() {
  const [geoData, setGeoData] = useState({ lat: 64.536634, lng: 16.779852 });

  return (
    <MapContainer center={[geoData.lat, geoData.lng]} zoom={12} style={{ height: '90vh' }}>
      <TileLayer
         attribution='&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
         url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
       />
      {geoData.lat && geoData.lng && (
        <Marker position={[geoData.lat, geoData.lng]} />
      )}
    </MapContainer>
  );
}
```

```
// this is a "barrel file" that prevents the ClientMap from ever getting loaded in the server.
export const Map: FunctionComponent = () => {
    const [Client, setClient] = useState<FunctionComponent>();

    useEffect(() => {
        (async () => {
            if (typeof global.window !== "undefined") {
                const newClient = (await import('./MapClient')).default
                setClient(() => newClient);
            }
        })();
    }, [])

    if (typeof global.window === "undefined" || !Client) {
        return null;
    }
    
    return Client ? <Client {...props} /> : null;
}
```

The goal is to guarantee that leaflet and related code never ever gets executed on the server. I opened a thread on Next 13 app dir discussion to see if there is a more standard way to write this code [here](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/41745#discussioncomment-4065197)

Comment: Could you elaborate on the barrel file? It's not entirely obvious to me, after researching, how it exists alongside the component

Comment: Sorry for the late response, but this apparently solved the problem, at least for now

Answer (score 6):

you have to import whether map component dynamically to force it to load 100% on the client side

```
const Map = dynamic(() => import("@/components/map"), {
    loading: () => <p>loading...</p>,
    ssr: false
})
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm having this same issue as well, sometimes it happens, sometimes it doesn't. Not the most helpful error message either...

However, I did notice that you possibly have the pages "api/" in the "app/" which is supposed to stay in "pages/" for now as per docs: https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/data-fetching/api-routes. Probably won't resolve anything, but possibly prevent some future issues.

Comment: Thanks, I already have changed the directory. I'm using the two routing systems, as this made LeafLet work for me.

Comment: @JoãoDaniloZucolotto, cool, I figured. I think I may have resolved it. I created a new project with next 13 and just reimported things incrementally. For me, there may have been some misconfiguration when upgrading. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

The issue mostly occurs when you using app routing. The leaflet is not optimized for NextJs.

This can be solved by importing the component dynamically (you can learn dynamic loading from the [NextJs official documentation](https://nextjs.org/learn/seo/improve/dynamic-import-components)).

```
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic';
const Mapa = dynamic(() => import('../components/Mapa'), { 
ssr: false,
})
```

Then use your component.

Answer (score 1):

My solution to the map component loading problem is to create 2 files, 1 to load the map separately and another for the client to use.

What do I mean by this, that in the file that is mapcomponent, it is responsible for loading the map component without having to start it on the server side, this prevents the map from being overwritten and not starting correctly, for them in the file where We use the "use client" we must dynamically load the component that we want to use on the client. For this, there is the functionality of next js, which is dynamic, which allows us to dynamically load the client-side component without having to stumble with starting it in the server.

The version of next js that was used is: 13.5.4

Example using

File 1: herolocation.tsx

```bash
"use client";
import { useState } from "react";
import dynamic from "next/dynamic";

// Componente: HeroLocation
const DynamicMap = dynamic(() => import("./mapcomponent"), { ssr: false });

export default function HeroLocation() {
    const [geoData, setGeoData] = useState({ lat: 64.536634, lng: 16.779852 });

    return (
        <>
            <div className="hero min-h-screen bg-neutral text-black">
                <div className="hero-content text-center">
                    <div className="max-w-md">
                        <h1 className="text-5xl font-bold m-2">Location in the Map</h1>
                        <DynamicMap geoData={geoData} />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </>
    );
}
```

File 2: mapcomponent.tsx

```bash
import { MapContainer, TileLayer, Marker } from "react-leaflet";
import "leaflet/dist/leaflet.css";

export default function MapComponent({ geoData }: any) {
    return (
        <MapContainer center={[geoData.lat, geoData.lng]} zoom={12} style={{ height: "500px" }}>
            <TileLayer
                attribution='&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
                url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
            />
            {geoData.lat && geoData.lng && <Marker position={[geoData.lat, geoData.lng]} />}
        </MapContainer>
    );
};
```

Easy solution a you problem.