# react-leaflet throwing errors under nextjs13

Tags: reactjs, next.js, leaflet, react-leaflet

I am trying to get a Leaflet map running under the new NextJS13 thinking with the distinctly declared client-side functions it should save me some trouble. But i cant get it to work. my map component looks like this:

```
"use client"
import React from 'react'
import { MapContainer, TileLayer } from 'react-leaflet'

const LeafletMap = () => {
  return (
    <MapContainer center={[51.505, -0.09]} zoom={13} scrollWheelZoom={false}>
      <TileLayer
        attribution='&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
        url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
      />
    </MapContainer>
  )
}

export default LeafletMap
```

and my page looks like this:

```
import styles from './page.module.css'
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic'
import { Suspense } from 'react'

export default function Home() {

  const Map = dynamic(
    () => import('./(components)/LeafletMap/LeafletMap'),
    { 
      suspense: true,
      ssr: false
    }
  )

  return (
    <div className={styles.container}>
      <h1>Collab Mapping</h1>
      <Suspense fallback={`Loading...`}>
        <Map/>
      </Suspense>
    </div>
  )
}
```

The error message i am getting is

```
client.js?234c:691 Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function
    at String (<anonymous>)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///(sc_server)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react/cjs/react.shared-subset.development.js:135:28)
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at printWarning
...
```

My initial hope was that declaring "use client" on the Map component would be enough to have it running on the client-side only. But it threw the error "window is undefined", telling me it is still trying to run on the server somehow.

So i thought i go back to my old approach and use next/dynamic with SSR turned off to make it work (and not use "use client") but then it gave me the error that i am using usestate and useeffect on server-side code (since i dont use those hooks in my code i believe they are used by react-leaflet internally).

So i tried combining both approaches, as in the code above, leading to this "object is not a function" error that i completely dont understand.

Someone has any ideas on that?

Comment: First can you move the `Map` declaration outside your component?

Comment: i have moved the map declaration in its own component, same error message

Comment: I would also expect your first approach ("use client" on Map) to work. But I am getting the same error. Here's the reproducer: https://stackblitz.com/edit/nextjs-tgxkck?file=components%2FMap.jsx

Comment: There was a similar question discussed earlier this month 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74289687/leaflet-implementation-on-next-js-13

Answer (score 0):

This is how I load my leaflet components for nextjs

```js
interface MapProps extends LeafletMapProps {}

const Map: React.FC<MapProps> = (props) => {
  const Map = React.useMemo(
    () =>
      dynamic(() => import("src/components/Map/Leaflet/LeafletMap"), {
        loading: () => <Skeleton height={"400px"} />,
        ssr: false,
      }),
    []
  );
  return <Map {...props} />;
};
```

Comment: i had it similarly in NextJS 12 and it worked, in NextJS 13 that not anymore, if I try exactly this snippet i am getting the same error plus a hydration mismatch error. Interesting idea to wrap the mapLoader into useMemo hook, whats the idea there? wouldnt the map already by default only rerender when props change?

Comment: Are us using any beta features, from next 13, e.g. app directory instead of pages? 
I have tested this on next 13 and it works, however I use pages and not app. I dont use `"use client"` either

Comment: yes i am using the app directory, if i go back to the usual "pages-folder" structure and omit the use of "use client" it works as intended, must be that the "app-folder" feature is unstable